# Renaming a table in the QGIS DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

When creating a PostGIS table (e.g. 'lakes') in the DB Manger a primary key ('lakes_pkey'), a index ('sidx_lakes_geom) and a sequence ('lakes_gid_seq') are also created.

[image]

But when renaming the table (e.g. 'lakes_2015'), the constraint, the index and the sequence don't get new names.

[image]

So it's not possible to create a new table named 'lakes' after renaming the original table 'lakes'.

```
Error: Relation „sidx_lakes_geom“ already exists
```

Is this a bug? (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13823)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it a bug or a missing feature that the constraint, the index and the sequence don't get new names when renaming the table in the DB Manager?

Comment: There is no strict rules to name indexes and sequence. DB Manager follows this naming schema. You may face to similar problem if DB Manager would rename indexes and sequences and those names are already used in the database. Rename them manually using psql or pgadmin.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, but only in relation to the index. The way PostgreSQL automatically creates primary keys and sequences should normally take care of this kind of name collision. The problem is that QGIS is creating the spatial index and whoever programmed that feature didn't think of your use-case.

To avoid this, instead of renaming your table. Create a new target table and `INSERT` your data from your source table to the target table before then truncating your source table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I suppose this will cause new issues when a view depends on the source table.

Comment: Similar issue: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164674/how-can-i-properly-rename-a-table-in-a-spatialite-db

Comment: Care to elaborate on your concern regarding views? And can you explain what you're trying to accomplish with renaming?